# Read text file on Android with Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am simply trying to read a text file on my Android with Phonegap. I have looked at all of the examples and I don't see a difference in my code. The file has lines of text. onloadend results in length of 0. There are no errors. What am I missing here?

```
    function readTextFile(fileName) {
                               window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 5*1024*1024,
       successCallback, errorCallback);
                               function successCallback(fs) {
                                   fs.root.getFile(fileName, {}, function(fileEntry) {
                                       fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                                           var reader = new FileReader();
                                           reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                                               console.log("TEXT FILE LENGTH: " + this.result.length);
                                           };
                                           reader.readAsText(file);
                                       }, errorCallback);
                                   }, errorCallback);
                               }

                               function errorCallback(error) {
                                   console.log("ERROR: " + error.code);
                               }



}
```